# ngrx effect - catchError: returning of does not end stream, and the API call does not re-run

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient, ngrx-effects

I have an effect in NgRX effect, as follows:

```js
$createOrganisation = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisation),
    switchMap((data) => this.organisation.createOrganisation(data)),
    map((response) => fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationSuccess({ orgId: response.id })),
    catchError((error) => {
      return of(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationError(error));
    })
  )
);
```

However, my stream never seems to end when the `catchError` is triggered, i.e. in the instance of `this.organisation.createOrganisation` returning a 400 error.

The action, `fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationError(error)` is triggered and my reducer is triggered from this... but if I re-trigger the `fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisation` effect, this effect runs but the API call is never made a second time.

If I configure it as follows, and dispatch it manually, it works:

```js
$createOrganisation = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisation),
    switchMap((data) => this.organisation.createOrganisation(data)),
    map((response) => fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationSuccess({ orgId: response.id })),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.store.dispatch(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationError(error));
      return throwError(error);
    })
  )
);
```

But other examples online suggest the first way should work, but it is not for me, and I do not understand why my stream never ends.

Can somebody please advise and tell me why my stream never ends in the first instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catchError should be added to the inner observable.

```
$createOrganisation = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisation),
    switchMap((data) => this.organisation.createOrganisation(data).pipe (
      map((response) => 
        fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationSuccess({ orgId: response.id })),
      catchError((error) => {
        return of(fromOrganisationActions.createOrganisationError(error));
      })
    )),
  )
);
```

These mistakes can be caught with [eslint-plugin-ngrx](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx#readme), more details about the rule [here](https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unsafe-catch.md).

Comment: Nice. And thanks! What's the actual difference between having the `catchError` on the inner-observable? I thought the result of the observables is the same, in this instance? I'm installing that plugin now!